# CTE and closing semi colons

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a recursive CTE that references another CTE written before it.

The first cte `nodes` I've closed-off with a semicolon before writing the recursive `Hierarchy` cte:

```
WITH nodes(node, node_name, parent, parent_name) AS
(
    SELECT      
        Grp.PermissionGroupID as node,
        Grp.GroupName as node_name,
        GrpLink.ParentPermissionGroupID as parent,
        ParentGrp.GroupName as parent_name
    FROM _CCC_Permission_Group Grp
    LEFT JOIN   _CCC_Permission_GroupGroup GrpLink
    on          Grp.PermissionGroupID = GrpLink.ChildPermissionGroupID
    LEFT JOIN   _CCC_Permission_Group ParentGrp
    on          GrpLink.ParentPermissionGroupID = ParentGrp.PermissionGroupID

);

WITH Hierarchy(node, node_name, depth, parent, parent_name)
AS
(
    SELECT      
        node,
        node_name,
        0,
        parent,
        parent_name
    FROM nodes as FirstDepth
    WHERE parent IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        NextDepth.node,
        NextDepth.node_name,
        Parent.depth + 1,
        Parent.parent,
        Parent.parent_name              
    FROM nodes as NextDepth
    INNER JOIN  Hierarchy as Parent
    on          NextDepth.parent = Parent.parent

)

SELECT      *
FROM        Hierarchy
OPTION      (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

I get the error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 17 Incorrect syntax near ';'.

When I remove the semicolon, I get the errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 19 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'WITH'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 19 Incorrect syntax near the
>   keyword 'with'. **If this statement is a common table expression**, an
>   xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, **the previous
>   statement must be terminated with a semicolon**.

...I don't write CTEs (let alone recursive ones) that often, so I'm not too sure how to resolve this apparent conflict with the `;` placement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `CTE` needs only one `WITH` clause. You can create `stacked CTE` by just adding comma at the end of previous `CTE` followed by CTE name

```
;WITH nodes(node, node_name, parent, parent_name) AS
(
....
),Hierarchy(node, node_name, depth, parent, parent_name)
AS
(
..
)
SELECT *
FROM   Hierarchy
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
```

Answer (score 2):

You only use a closing semi-colon at the end of the statement. All the CTEs form a single statement. When using multiple CTEs in a single statement, separate each CTE using a comma.

```
WITH nodes(node, node_name, parent, parent_name) AS
    ...
), Hierarchy(node, node_name, depth, parent, parent_name) AS (
    ...
)
SELECT ...
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

Note the semi-colon at the end. You should get in to the habit of including this as in the future more statements will require it (e.g. the MERGE statement must be terminated using a semi-colon).